# Anyway to pass a variable to bc, having a command to be executed?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bc

I need to pass certain variable to `bc` to get the output in floating point,

```
var1=$((<some operation>))
var2=$((<some operation>))      #Needs var1
var3=$((<some operation>))      #Needs var2
bc -l <<< $var3                 #Need output in Floating points
```

**Output:**

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
```

Anyway to overcome this?

**Update:**

```
diff=$(($epoc2-$epoc1))
var1=$(($diff / 60))
var2=$(($var1 / 57))
var3=`bc <<< 'scale=2; $var2'`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple quotes don't expand `$` variable. You have to use double quotes:

```
var3=`bc <<< "scale=2; $var2"`
```

On the other hand, `$var1` and `$var2` won't store float (`bash` doesn't manage them), so you `bc` instead.

```
diff=$(($epoc2-$epoc1))
var1=$(bc <<< "scale=3 ; $diff / 60")
var2=$(bc <<< "scale=3 ; $var1 / 57")
var3=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $var2")
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression isn't expanded because of the single ticks `'`.

Use something like:

```
var3=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $var2")
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message means you have a literal dollar sign in your input to `bc`. In the shell, [single quotes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02) preserve the literal value of each character. Use [double quotes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) to interpolate variables:

```
bc <<< "scale=2; $var2"
```

This probably won't get the output you want, though, because `bc` does not generally truncate or pad input values. You can trick it using a no-op division:

```
bc <<< "scale=2; $var2 / 1"
```

That will enforce 2dp scale on the output.

---

It would be simpler (and likely more accurate) to do it all in the calculator, though - both `var1` and `var2` will have the results of integer division in Bash and POSIX sh.

```
var3=`bc <<< "scale = 2 ; $diff / 60 / 57"`
```

This will give the mathematically correct answer, appropriately rounded. If you want integer behaviour and `bc` scaling for some reason, you can use the other version.

Answer (score 2):

If your bc calculations are somewhat involved, you could also use HERE docs to make it more readable:

```
var2=500
bc << EOF
scale=2
$var2 + 100
EOF
```

prints out

```
600
```